# Finite resolution by sums of line bundles on toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

I hope I wasn't searching wrong keywords or overlooking some easy arguments to prove/disprove it. What I'm asking is the following:

Let $X$ be a smooth complete toric variety. $\mathcal F$ a coherent sheaf (or a torus equivariant one if the previous one does not work). Does $\mathcal F$ always admit a finite resolution by sums of line bundles, i.e., a resolution of $\mathcal F$ that looks like

$$0\rightarrow\bigoplus_{i=1}^{a_n}L_{i,n}\rightarrow\dotsb\rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^{a_0}L_{i,0}\rightarrow\mathcal F\rightarrow 0$$

Comment: This is definitely true if $X$ has a full exceptional collection consisting of line bundles. This happens quite often for small dimension or small Picard rank, however not always.

Comment: @Sasha: Do you have a counter-example (with $X$ a smooth toric variety)?

Comment: See Efimov: arXiv:1010.3755 for a smooth toric Fano variety without a full, strong exceptional collection of line bundles.

Comment: @Sasha If you don't mind, could you tell me how to get the resolution from a full exceptional collection of line bundles? Thanks very much.

Comment: @abx: I had in mind the paper of Efimov which was mentioned by Richard in his comment.

Comment: @Honglu: This is an analogue of the Beilinson spectral sequence which one always has in presence of a full exceptional collection. Using the collection and its dual one can write a resolution of the diagonal sheaf, and then use it to construct a resolution of an arbitrary object in the derived category.

Comment: @Sasha So far I still couldn't figure out how one gets a resolution from even the Beilinson spectral sequence in $P^2$. I feel that spectral sequence might get to a few nonzero terms which just tell us about some quotients of a filtration of a sheaf...

Comment: @Honglu: The trick is to twist first the sheaf by a sufficiently ample line bundle to ensure that all higher cohomology vanish. Then Beilinson spectral sequence gives you a resolution, which you then twist back.

Comment: @sasha Got it! Thank you very much!